# Ghidra C dissasembly shows never seen code statement? Keyword "code" with pointer operator

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ghidra

Playing with ghidra and there is this statement on the disassembly display that i don't understand.

```
(**(code **)
```

For example in this context:

```
int *piVar1;
int iVar2;

uVar3 = (**(code **)(*piVar1 + 8))(iVar2);
```

The internet did not had any good results due to that pointer operator that the search machine doesn't accept.

Comment: Looks like it treats `(*piVar1 + 8)` as a pointer to a pointer to a function and then calls that? The original assembly is probably more explicit. You should edit your question to include it.

Comment: Might be an idea to post the associated assembly instructions.

Comment: Could this be a virtual function call of C++ code? `piVar1` is a pointer the the object. It contains the *vtable* at the start. Within the *vtable*, the function at offset 8 is looked up and then called with `iVar2` as the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`code` is not a C keyword or reserved identifier.  From context, it looks like Ghidra is using it as a generic representation of a function, such that `code **` means pointer to pointer to function.  Ghidra might do this because without knowing the function's return type, it cannot form a correct function-pointer type name for it.  Or perhaps it just thinks the form it is using is clearer.

In any case, in C, this expression ...

```
(**(code **)(*piVar1 + 8))(iVar2)
```

... is a function call, with `(**(code **)(*piVar1 + 8))` as function designator and with `iVar2` as argument.  Presumably, the double dereference is present in the binary code, and Ghidra invents the `(code **)` cast to make it sensible. It follows that `*piVar1 + 8` is (used as) a pointer to a pointer to a function, so overall that looks like a function being called via a dispatch table.

A call to a C++ member function via an object's vtable might look much like that, but the same general form might be used in certain C code, too.

Comment: that explains so much. Thank you